# Test class Of a Trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test, failing-tests

Here is the trigger

```
trigger UpdateNumberOfQuantityInstallments on OpportunityLineItem(before insert) 
{
List<product2> lstProduct2 = new List<product2>();
for(OpportunityLineItem oli : trigger.new)
{
    if(oli.quantity != null)
    {
        product2 prod = new product2();
        prod.id = oli.product2id;
        system.debug('id = '+prod.id);
        prod.CanUseQuantitySchedule = true;
        prod.NumberOfQuantityInstallments = oli.quantity.intValue();
        prod.QuantityScheduleType = 'Divide';
        prod.QuantityInstallmentPeriod = 'Monthly';
        system.debug('no = '+prod.NumberOfQuantityInstallments );   
        lstProduct2.add(prod);                       
    }
}
if(!lstProduct2.isEmpty()) upsert lstProduct2;
}
```

Test Class is

```
@isTest
private class UpdateNumberOfQuantityInstallmentsTest
{
static testmethod void test()
{
    List<Product2> lstProduct2 = new List<Product2>();
    Opportunity o = new Opportunity();
    o.name = 'Anzar';
    o.closedate = system.today();
    o.Accountid = '001P000000eKRC8';
    o.Type = 'New Business';
    o.Work_Start_Date__c = system.today().AddDays(30);
    o.StageName ='Prospect';
    o.amount = 10000;
    o.Segments__c = 'Case Hole Wireline';
    o.Sub_Segment__c = 'TCP';
    o.Operating_Area__c = 'Barnett';
    insert o;
    OpportunityLineItem oli = new OpportunityLineItem();
    oli.product2.name = 'GenWatt Diesel 1000kW';
    oli.opportunityid = o.id;
    oli.quantity = 4;
    oli.UnitPrice = 250;
    insert oli;
    product2 prod = new product2();
    prod.id = oli.product2id;
    prod.NumberOfQuantityInstallments = 4;
    prod.QuantityScheduleType = 'Divide';
    prod.QuantityInstallmentPeriod = 'Monthly';  
    lstProduct2.add(prod);    
    insert lstProduct2;
}
}
```

I am getting this error
System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
Class.UpdateNumberOfQuantityInstallmentsTest.test: line 20, column 1

Comment: can you plz tell, what is the 20th line in this Test class?

Comment: @Subhash thanks for the reply...My test class is completed now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't set it in this way

```
oli.product2.name = 'GenWatt Diesel 1000kW';
```

Instead you need to give productId here

```
Product2 prod = new Product2(Name = 'Laptop X200', 
                                     Family = 'Hardware');
        insert prod;
oli.product2Id = prod.Id;
```

So for that you need to create product record first and then assign Id.

Comment: I would suggest you Anzar to put some Asserts in your test class, otherwise your test class isn't actually testing nothing, just following lines of instructions without checking if the results are the expected ones.

Comment: If this is from a Sandbox -> Production test, you will need to create an Account into de test for the Opportunity. Never use directly Id Strings to assign Ids.